# How can I print the max and min value of an array?

Tags: java

I need to write a program that stores the total rainfall for 12 months then show an output of the total, average, the month with the highest, and lowest rainfall. My program runs but but I don't know how to make the output the number of the month instead of the amount of rainfall in that month. 
For example when I have, Enter rain fall for month 6: 15.6 My output should be 6 not 15.6. Thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rainfall
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
       double[] rain = new double[12]; // The rainfall data

       getValues(rain);
       showValues(rain);
       System.out.println("The total rainfall for this year is: " + totalRain(rain));
       System.out.println("The average rainfall for this year is: " + averageRain(rain));
       System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is: " + mostRain(rain));
       System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain is: " + leastRain(rain));
    }

   /**
      showValues method
      @param  rain Display the rainfall array
   */
    public  static void showValues(double[] rain)
    {

    }

   /**
      getValues method
      @return The rain array filled with user input
   */
    public  static void getValues(double[] array)
    {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

          for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
          {
                System.out.println("Enter rain fall for month " + (i + 1) + ".");
                array[i] = scan.nextDouble();
          }
    }

   /**
      getTotal method
      @return The total of the elements in
      the rainfall array.
   */

   public static double totalRain(double[] rain)
   {
       double total = 0.0;     // Accumulator

      // Accumulate the sum of the elements
      // in the rainfall array.
      for (int index = 0; index < rain.length; index++)
         //total += sales[index];
         total = total + rain[index];

      // Return the total.
      return total;
   }

   /**
      getAverage method
      @return The average of the elements
      in the rainfall array.
   */

   public static double averageRain(double[] rain)
   {
      return totalRain(rain) / rain.length;
   }

   /**
      getHighest method
      @return The highest value stored
      in the rainfall array.
   */

   public static double mostRain(double[] rain)
   {
      double highest = rain[0];

      for (int index = 1; index < rain.length; index++)
      {
         if (rain[index] > highest)
            highest = rain[index];
      }

      return highest;
   }

   /**
      getLowest method
      @returns The lowest value stored
      in the rainfall array.
   */

   public static double leastRain(double[] rain)
   {
      double lowest = rain[0];

      for (int index = 1; index < rain.length; index++)
      {
         if (rain[index] < lowest)
            lowest = rain[index];
      }

      return lowest;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple method using JAVA 8 Streams:

```
Double[] doubles = new Double[12];


       List<Double> doubleList = Arrays.asList(doubles);


       Double max = doubleList.stream().mapToDouble(dub -> dub).max().getAsDouble();

       Double min = doubleList.stream().mapToDouble(dub -> dub).min().getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Instead of the amount of rain at the given index, you'd want the index istelf.

```
public static double mostRain(double[] rain)
   {
      double highest = rain[0];
      int highestMonth = 0;

      for (int index = 1; index < rain.length; index++)
      {
         if (rain[index] > highest)
            highest = rain[index];
            highestMonth = index;
      }

      return highestMonth;
   }
```